# Intermittent javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unqualified {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client fault

Tags: java, jboss, jbossws, solaris-10

We are using `JBossWS - Native (version 3.1.2)` (Standard JBoss EAP 5.1 installation) and we are intermitently getting the following exception..., anyone got a clue?

If I test with a few calls to the webservice it is working fine, but once deployed into production we start seeing this error.. most of the times it works fine.. but sometimes we see this error..

I would estimate about 10% of the web service calls are getting this error.

The web service client is generated using `wsconsume`

```
2011-11-17 09:35:05,652 ERROR [org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient] (ajp-10.1.75.243-8209-5) Exception caught while (preparing for) performing the invocation:
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unqualified {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client fault
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.getSOAPFaultException(SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.java:85)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.binding.SOAP11BindingJAXWS.throwFaultException(SOAP11BindingJAXWS.java:107)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPBinding.unbindResponseMessage(CommonSOAPBinding.java:558)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:396)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:231)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:171)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:157)
    at $Proxy234.searchCustomerIdEquip(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve the problem,

**FIRST STEP**

I upgrade my Solaris Java version from version `1.6.0_23` to version `1.6.0_27`. After upgrading **the exception changed** from `javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException`

```
ERROR [org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient] (ajp-10.1.75.243-8109-4) Exception caught while (preparing for) performing the invocation:
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unqualified {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client fault
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.getSOAPFaultException(SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.java:85)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.binding.SOAP11BindingJAXWS.throwFaultException(SOAP11BindingJAXWS.java:107)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPBinding.unbindResponseMessage(CommonSOAPBinding.java:558)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:396)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:231)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:171)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:157)
```

to `java.io.IOException`...

```
[org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient] (ajp-10.1.75.243-8109-1) Exception caught while (preparing for) performing the invocation:
java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message
    at org.jboss.ws.core.client.HTTPRemotingConnection.invoke(HTTPRemotingConnection.java:253)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.client.SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.invoke(SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.java:71)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:360)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:231)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:171)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:157)
```

**SECOND STEP**

After getting IOException, then I realised our load balancers probably not allowing chunked encoding.. so I changed Jboss configuration so that it does not use chunked encoding, edit the file below..

```
jboss-eap-5.1.0.GA/jboss-as/server/<instance>/deployers/jbossws.deployer/META-INF/standard-jaxws-client-config.xml
```

.. and set the `http://org.jboss.ws/http#chunksize` from `2048` to `0`

That did it!.. we are no longer having SOAPFaultException.